# Public array is not accessable in js class

Tags: javascript, oop

here's a part of the class :

```
function Table(seats){
    //editables
        var leaveTable_position=new Array('380','0','102','20');

    //runtime
        Table.id=0;
        Table.max_buy=0;
        Table.min_buy=0;
        Table.player_timeout=0;

    //on creation
        Table.seat=new Array();
        if (seats<5){seats=5;}
        if (seats>5){seats=9;}
        for (var i=1 ; i<=seats ; i++){
            Table.seat[i]=new Seat(i);
            Table.seat[i].create();
        }}
```

you see the Table.seat public array ?
assuming i have 3 seats (table.seat[0]; table.seat[2];) ...

the following code gives me 'seat is undefined' !!!

```
table=new Table();
table.seat[2].getUser();
```

any ideas why ? am not that good in js oop !

Comment: You might want to read this MSDN tutorial on OOP programming in javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript. In particular, that javascript is Prototype-based programming in which "is a style of object-oriented programming in which classes are not present, and behavior reuse (known as inheritance in class-based languages) is accomplished through a process of decorating existing objects which serve as prototypes"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `Table` use `this`.

For example:

```
//runtime
    this.id=0;
    this.max_buy=0;
    this.min_buy=0;
    this.player_timeout=0;
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/a7H57/3/

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `this` instead of Table. When using `Table`, you're modifying properties on the `Table` function.

If you use `this`, the properties are defined on the current instance of the `Table` "class". If you still want to prefix `Table`, declare `var Table = this` inside your function. A side-effect of this is that you cannot directly call `Table()` from inside the function any more.

```
function Table(seats){
        var Table = this;
    //editables
        var leaveTable_position=new Array('380','0','102','20');

    //runtime
        Table.id=0;
        Table.max_buy=0;
        Table.min_buy=0;
        Table.player_timeout=0;

    //on creation
        Table.seat=new Array();
        if (seats<5){seats=5;}
        if (seats>5){seats=9;}
        for (var i=1 ; i<=seats ; i++){
            Table.seat[i]=new Seat(i);
            Table.seat[i].create();
        }}
```